# Resolve Webpack 5.9.0 deprecation calls [DEP_WEBPACK_DEPRECATION_ARRAY_TO_SET] and [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_MODULES_ITERABLE]

Tags: deprecation-warning, webpack-5

I have a couple webpack 5.9 build warnings which are giving me some difficulty in resolving.

I have researched as best I could online to no avail. I did find this:

[Webpack 5 release docs: Arrays to Sets](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#arrays-to-sets)

However, except that I understand the concepts, I have no idea how to change my config settings to resolve this. Same is true for how to switch up things to "Use new ChunkGraph API".

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
yarn run build
```

(node:90180) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEPRECATION_ARRAY_TO_SET] DeprecationWarning: chunk.files was changed from Array to Set (using Array method 'includes' is deprecated)
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:90180) [DEP_WEBPACK_CHUNK_MODULES_ITERABLE] DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modulesIterable: Use new ChunkGraph API

Update:

I have discovered through using:

```
node --trace-deprecation node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --mode=development
```

that both of these deprecation warnings occur only when using purge-css-webpack-plugin. I am using it like so (which I learned from following: https://survivejs.com/webpack/styling/eliminating-unused-css/):

```
      new PurgeCSSWebpackPlugin({
        // paths: ALL_FILES,
        paths: purgePath,
        extractors: [
            {
              extractor: (content) =>
                content.match(/[^<>"'`\s]*[^<>"'`\s:]/g) || [],
              extensions: ["html"],
            },
        ],          
    }),
```

Still not sure how to resolve the warnings, but at least getting closer. Also, pondering other options to remove unused CSS....

Latest Update

For @Ashish and others who my read this: I did resolve this. However, I must apologize for not updating this topic when I did b/c now I can't remember how I did it. I believe I updated some packages in my package.json to latest. Also, I currently use purge css webpack plugin like so:

```
`new PurgeCSSWebpackPlugin({
    paths: globAll.sync(
      [
        `${path.resolve(__dirname, './src')}/**/*`,
        `${path.resolve(__dirname, './public')}/**/*`
      ],  
      { nodir: true }
   ),
 }),`
```

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 9):

This might be unrelated to CSS but I had the same issue because I was using a old version a old version of the ts-loader so I've installed the latest.

`npm i -D ts-loader@latest`

Comment: Hi, @Lucio Poveda, yes, I believe my solution involved updating some packages to '@latest'. This process of updating packages was new to me at the time, so it took me some time to understand, and I did not document properly what exactly resolved my issue. I'm glad you posted here. Thanks for taking time to share your solution.

Comment: For me updating ts-loader to 9.5.1 solved the issue